# Open a facebook page from android app?

Tags: android, android-intent, facebook-android-sdk

How can I start an intent to open a Facebook application on a phone and navigate to the prefered page in Facebook?

I tried:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana", "com.facebook.katana.ProfileTabHostActivity");
intent.putExtra("extra_user_id", "123456789l");
this.startActivity(intent);
```

Well, whatever I write to "1234567891", it is always navigating to my page. Always to me and not else.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exactly same problem, sent the user id but for some reason, my profile always opened instead of the friend's profile.

The problem is that if you pass the `String` of the `Long` object that represents the Facebook UID, or even a `long` primitive type, the intent won't be able to read it later. You need to pass a real `Long`.

So the complete code is:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana", "com.facebook.katana.ProfileTabHostActivity");
    Long uid = new Long("123456789");
    intent.putExtra("extra_user_id", uid);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Ok enjoy and hope this helps :-)

Maxim

Comment: This solution won't work any more. You can find the answer in the following link http://stackoverflow.com/a/13107858/1020530

Comment: Hey, this is not a good solution since it explicitly uses ProfileTabHostActivity. In future version Facebook could decide to rename that activity or remove it from the app. Then your solution wouldn't work.

Answer (score 11):

Here is the best and simple way to do it.
Just follow the code

```
public final void Facebook() {
        final String urlFb = "fb://page/"+yourpageid;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(urlFb));

        // If Facebook application is installed, use that else launch a browser
        final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> list =
            packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        if (list.size() == 0) {
            final String urlBrowser = "https://www.facebook.com/pages/"+pageid;
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(urlBrowser));
        }

        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: It worked but in new facebook update the link to page is "https://www.facebook.com/"+pageid;  this instead of "https://www.facebook.com/pages/"+pageid;

Answer (score 1):

try this code :

```
String facebookUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/<id_here>";
    try {
        int versionCode = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0).versionCode;
        if (versionCode >= 3002850) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" + facebookUrl);
               startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
        } else {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("fb://page/<id_here>");
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(facebookUrl)));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution won't work any more. The new version of the facebook app doesn't support anymore those kind of intents. See [here](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/286768364773190?browse=search_508cf5471018a7b63754513) the bug report

The new solution is to use the iPhone scheme mechanism (Yes, facebook decided to support the iPhone mechanism in Android instead of the implicit intent mechanism of Android).

So in order to open the facebook app with a user profile all you need to do is:

```
String facebookScheme = "fb://profile/" + facebookId;
Intent facebookIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(facebookScheme)); 
startActivity(facebookIntent);
```

If you are looking for other actions you can use the [following page](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes) for all available actions (/you have to test it though, since I didn't find an official publication of facebook about this)