# How do I interface with Facebook's API through my own Android application?

Tags: android, facebook

I want people who use my Android application to be able to log into `Facebook` or go to a specific profile.  How do I interface with Facebook's app so I can open it and ask it to open certain pags that I specify (as opposed to the "home" which shows every time one logs into Facebook)?

EDITOR NOTE: Android is assumed since the question is tagged "android".

Comment: Did you check [Facebook complite guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/)?

Comment: no, my question doesn't use a connection to facebook... so i figured I looked it up in the web and ask in the forum because i'm trying to interfaciate withh an app, what if I wanted to use an app that is not facebook's? I don't think it's related to facebook programing

Answer (score 1):

Read through [this guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/) to get started with the Android Facebook SDK...

And here is the [homepage](https://developers.facebook.com/android/) for the Android SDK

So to clarify, do you want users of your app to view specific facebook content from within your app? Or you want to link them to this specific content in the facebook app from your app? I.e., a profile page.

Either way, check out [this SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107857/android-facebook-intent-to-show-profile-with-class-com-facebook-katana-profileta/13107858#13107858) for specifics about the new way to use Intents in your Android app to link to Facebook app content.

Comment: the second option, link them to the specific content in the facebook app

Comment: i'm not sure I understand, the class com.facebook.katana.ProfileTabHostActivity opens the profile in my app? lets say I don't have facebook's app on my phone, would it still open the profile?