# Open a facebook page works only when facebook is in background

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

I used the code that I found in this page [Open a facebook page from android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299777/open-a-facebook-page-from-android-app)

```
    facebookButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {

                getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://page/[page_id]"));
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com/[page_name]")));
            }
        }
    });
```

But, if facebook is not open in background, when I click the button the facebook app opens itself in homepage.
If facebook is in background, I see the right page.

How could I open the right page even facebook is not in background?

Thanks :)